# Script to grep large file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file that has about 63000 row I need to grep though

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinks.txt
69870  1.pdf.Published
125098 2.png.Published
125022 3.pdf.Published
69867  4.png.Published
```

I have a list of 450 numbers that will match some of the row in the missinglinks.txt file

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinksA.sh
125105
125104
125103
125102
125100
125099
125098
125097
125022
```

I am trying to use a script to take the first row from missinglinksA.sh and grep missinglinks.txt and output to a file, then the second, n.....

```
for n in $(cat missinglinksA.txt)
do
    cat missinglinks.txt | grep $n
done
```

I would like an output file like:

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinksAout.txt
125098 2.png.Published
125022 3.pdf.Published
```

I cannot however get the output either on the screen or to a text file, I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if the script is simply not outputing.

I have -o -i none seem to fix the issue.

I can do:

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125098 >> missinglinksAout.txt
```

And it works.

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinksAout.txt
125098 2.png.Published
```

I have taken the top 10 rows from the missinglinksA.txt file and made a script to check each line and that does not work either, blank output.

```
[root@server]# cat missinglinksAtesteachline.sh
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125105
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125104
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125103
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125102
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125100
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125099
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125098
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125097
cat missinglinksA.txt | grep 125022

[root@server]# sh missinglinksAtesteachline.sh
[root@server]#
```

Comment: I think you'll have an easier time solving this if you use some quotes and maybe "grep --color=never" just to minimize confusion.

Comment: maybe fgrep is better on huge files ; you can olso prefer to use -F & -f to optimize the search.  another way is to `while read -r line ; 
do ; grep pattern $line >> /tmp/output_result.$(date +%Y%m%d).txt ; 
done < inputfile`  You can also search on the stackexhange "read huge file" maybe to get more methods and find the best for your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the copies from your "cats", i can use yield the expected results with the following command:

```
$ fgrep -f missingLinksA.txt missingLinks.txt 
125098 2.png.Published
125022 3.pdf.Published
```

I hope this helps.